# how to install xeus-cling with archiconda3?

Tags: xeus-cling

I want to use C/C++ on jupyter notebook so I installed archiconda3 on my development board which has arm64 architecture.

After create and activate an conda environmemt, when I try to install xeus-cilng with

```
conda install -c conda-forge xeus-cling
```

I get the following error message:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- xeus-cling

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-aarch64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/c4aarch64/linux-aarch64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/c4aarch64/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

https://anaconda.org

does it means that xeus-cling is not supported for linux aarch64?